# How does bluebird know to proceed to the next `then` in this chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, chaining

Having promisified fs-extra, I understand that I can use `then` to access the files. I *guess* there is some mechanism there that after it gets the file it knows to move to the next link in the `then` chain. However, the next `then` I've just put a simple for-loop. And the next one just prints a line to the console. I would expect some sort of Promise object to be returned for it to move down the chain. What is required to proceed down this chain? For example, if I put in a setTimeout for a second, then chain continues and prints out of order.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
  , fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'))

fs.readdirAsync(dir)
    .bind(this)
    .then((files) => {
        this.files = files;
    })
    .then(() => {
        var num = 10000
        this.files.forEach((file, index, array) => {
            for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
                console.log(num*i);
            }
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('middle of it');
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('done with it');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: It's the same as doing something like `Promise.resolve(null).then(whatever)`. If there's no actual task wrapped in the promise, the promise immediately resolves.

Comment: @AR7 How would you solve for adding the timeout in that case? [The docs for `.timeout`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/timeout.html) make it look as though you can just put `.timeout(1000)` between `then`s, but that does not work.

Comment: You may like this, http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/

Comment: In short you will need to wrap setTimeout as a new Promise and return it for the chain to work properly after you add it. Otherwise it'll be executed out of the context of next promise in chain.

Comment: `you can just put .timeout(1000) between thens` - yes, but that wont delay anything, if you want a delay use [delay](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/delay.html) ... timeout returns a promise that will be fulfilled or rejected with the resolved/rejected value of the previous promise, except if the timeout expires, the promise will reject with a timeout error ... read the [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/timeout.html) carefully to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `.then()` returns a new promise that has its own `.then()` handlers.    That promise is automatically linked to the previous promise so when the previous promise is completely done with it's own `.then()` handler and that `.then()` handler didn't return a promise or if it did when that promise it returned is resolved, it can then trigger the next promise in the chain to be resolved causing it to repeat the cycle for it's `.then()` handlers.

The key is that `p.then()` returns a new promise that is itself resolved when `p.then()` is done so it can then trigger the next step in the chain `p.then().then()` and so on.

Keep in mind that a `.then()` handler can do one of four things:

1. Return nothing (same as returning `undefined`).
2. Return a value
3. Return a promise
4. Throw an exception

For the first two (returning a value), this just signifies that the `.then()` handler is done and then next one in the chain can be triggered now.

When returning a promise, that promise itself is hooked with `.then()` handlers so it can be monitored.  If/when it resolves, the chain continues.   If/when it rejects, the chain is rejected.  The promise that is returned may already be resolved or rejected or may be resolved or rejected in the future, no meaningful difference in behavior.  If the returned promise is never resolved or rejected, the promise chain is stalled and will not continue until it is resolved or rejected (same as any promise).

If the `.then()` handler throws an exception, this is caught by the `.then()` wrapper and it is automatically converted to a rejected promise with the exception as the reject reason.

> For example, if I put in a setTimeout for a second, then chain
>   continues and prints out of order.

You can't very effectively use `setTimeout()` by itself to delay a promise chain.  Instead, you need to return a promise from a `.then()` handler that is resolved after some timeout time.  Bluebird has `.delay(x)` that does that for you.

Or, you can code one yourself if not using Bluebird:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

fn().then(function() {
    // delay promise chain by 1000ms
    return delay(1000);
}).then(function() {
    // promise chain continues here
});
```

Or, with Bluebird promises, it's as simple as:

```
 fn().delay(1000).then(function() {
     delayed promise chain continues here
 });
```

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that it's always returns new promise like `Promise.resolve(undefined|value)` or `Promise.reject` on throws, if non-promise is returned??

Comment: @Annarfych - What always returns new promise?  `.then()` does always return a new promise.  It's a new promise that is itself resolved or rejected after the prior promise's `.then()` handler is done and any promise that it might have returned has fulfilled.

Comment: Yeah , I am talking about `then`. If that's the case you explanation can be simplified that any value returned converted to promise on wihich next `then` or `catch` acts.